# Silverlight 4 RelativeSource FindAncestor binding

Tags: .net, silverlight, binding, relativesource

Will there be RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType... in Silverlight 4?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Silverlight 4 the `RelativeSource` property of `Binding` still only supports "Self" and "TemplatedParent", there is no change from Silverlight 3 in this area.

Answer (score 16):

`RelativeSource AncestorType` [is supported in Silverlight 5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.ancestortype%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), which is available now.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
           FontSize="{Binding DataContext.CustomFontSize, 
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could instantiate the ViewModel in the XMAL as a static resource then reference that as the source in your binding.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:MainPageViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Partitions}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <toolkit:WrapPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight"  />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Margin="10,0" Width="40" Content="{Binding}" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

This may help:

http://blog.thekieners.com/2010/09/08/relativesource-binding-with-findancestor-mode-in-silverlight/